# React - Antd Modal Max Width [Modal.info() method]

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

```
const showModal = () => {
    Modal.info({
      title: "Title",
      maskClosable: true,
      content: (
        <div>
           Lorem ipsum dolor ... isit.
        </div>
      ),
      onOk() { },
    });
  };
```

How do I set max-width for this modal? Right now it spans across the entire page. I want the max-width of the modal to be 760px. In the documentation, there's a property called `width` but so far it has not worked for me. Same with `style`.

Here's a [link](https://ant.design/components/modal/) to documentation. The `Modal.info()` part is at the bottom of the page.

Please lmk how to set a max width.

Comment: It looks like you have some other style which overwrites antd style - is it possible?

Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

To set max width:

```
.class {
width: 100%;
max-width: 760px;
}
```

If you inspect the custom width model from the shared link: u will find that it is using

```
{
    width: auto;
    max-width: calc(100vw - 32px);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

in class `.ant-modal` which is getting override. So, check whether it's not been overridden by some other class for your project or you can use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'width' propertie after 'onOk()'

```
  const showModal = () => {
Modal.info({
  title: "Title",
  maskClosable: true,
  content: (
    <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor ... isit.
    </div>
  ),
  onOk() { },
  width:760
});
```

};